# Как создать форму правильно? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Делаю сайт с двумя моделям: категории и продукты (продукт относится к категории)

Вот все страницы:

Категории

```
GET /categories -> categories#index

GET /categories -> categories#show

GET /categories/new -> categories#new

POST /categories -> categories#create

GET /categories/ID -> categories#show

GET  /categories/ID/edit -> categories#edit

PATCH /categories/ID -> categories#update

DELETE /categories/ID -> categories#destroy
```

и для Продуктов

```
GET /categories/ID/products -> products#index

GET /categories/ID/products/new -> products#new

POST /categories/ID/products -> products#create

GET /products/ID -> products#show

GET /products/ID/edit -> products#edit

PATCH /products/ID -> products#update

DELETE /products/ID -> products#destroy
```

Надо сделать в /categories/ID/products/new форму для создания продукта.

product_controller.rb:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    #@product = Product.new(product_params) 
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = @category.products.create(product_params)
    redirect_to new_category_product_url(@category)
  end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @product = @category.products.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to category_path(@category)
  end

  private
  def product_params
    params.permit(:name)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories do
    resources :products
  end
end
```

products/new.html.erb  Здесь надо создать форму

Comment: Я думаю, эта [книга](https://vk.com/doc10903696_319056752) вам поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/views/products/new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Product</h1>

<%= render 'form', product: @product %>

<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

app/views/products/_form.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for(product) do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :category_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @сategory, :id, :name, { 
      include_blank: true }, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```